Is it valid C++ to destroy an object and construct a new object into the same variable?
I have a struct containing an object of some type T, which I know to have a noexcept default constructor.  I would like to expose a member function on my struct that replaces the old object with a new object.  However, T might not have an assignment operator, so I would need to destroy the old T and construct a new T into the same variable.
Thus, I would like to write code like this:
template <typename T>
class Container {
  private:
    T t{};
  public:
    template <typename... Args>
    void replace(Args&&... args) {
        // destroy the old T...
        std::destroy_at(&t);
        // ... and construct a new T in its place (or if it throws, we default-construct a T)
        try {
            std::construct_at(&t, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        } catch {
            std::construct_at(&t);
        }
    }
    // stuff that we might do on the object, both before and after the call to replace()
    void do_stuff() { t.do_stuff(); }
};

Is the above valid code, and is it possible to do things with the object before and after the replace operation without invoking undefined behaviour?  (Or perhaps it is undefined behaviour that could be made well-defined with a sprinkling of std::launder?)
I don't think this part is necessary to answer the question, but in the specific problem I'm trying to solve, T has reference-like semantics, and therefore assignment is akin to rebinding the reference, which T may not allow.
Note that this is a similar question, but the answers it has garnered only say one or more of the following:

It is bad practice to do this.
You end up with garbage when the constructor of T throws.
It works in practice.

I am however interested mainly in whether my code is well-defined according to the standard, and none of the answers there sufficiently address this.  In addition, the linked question was asked before it was possible to implement std::vector in standard C++.

C++ has std::reference_wrapper which has reference-like semantics and is rebindable.  In case a std solution is a better choice than a diy solution.

Thought the question is interesting, it's worth noting that it's moot. The normal way to handle things is to use alignas(T) std::byte t_buff[sizeof(T)]; and bool is_constructed, which can handle all the same cases, with none of the downsides, and is fully well-defined

@MooingDuck And instead of implementing it manually, one usually just uses std::optional which takes care of all of the tricky implementation details. It is also fully exception-safe, which this implementation is not if the default constructor in the second construction attempt throws.

While implementing it manually with the is_constructed flag or using std::optional will work, Container may become up to twice as large as it needs to be, since is_constructed will always be true / the std::optional will always contain a value.  We don't want to incur this unnecessary memory cost.

@Bernard then you need some other way to determine if there is no live object in the memory. There is no general solution to that. If you know that some or all fields in the class are never 0, then you could use those bytes as a is_constructed flag, but otherwise, you need additional space.

Well no you don't need to determine it, because as the class author, I know that there is always a live object in the memory.  If you know that the default constructor is noexcept, which is the case in this question, you can guarantee that the object is always constructed (i.e. the object being constructed is a class invariant), because you can just construct a default object in the space.

This is probably fine, depending on what exactly T is and how Container is used. T and Container must be transparently replaceable.
In C++20, the relevant passage is 6.7.3.8 in [basic.life] :


If, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or
released, a new object is created at the storage location which the original object occupied, a pointer that
pointed to the original object, a reference that referred to the original object, or the name of the original
object will automatically refer to the new object and, once the lifetime of the new object has started, can be
used to manipulate the new object, if:


(8.1) the storage for the new object exactly overlays the storage location which the original object occupied,
and
(8.2) the new object is of the same type as the original object (ignoring the top-level cv-qualifiers), and
(8.3) the original object is neither a complete object that is const-qualified nor a subobject of such an object,
and
(8.4) neither the original object nor the new object is a potentially-overlapping subobject (6.7.2)
(8.5) either the original object and the new object are both complete objects, or the original object and the new object are direct subobjects of objects p1 and p2, respectively, and p1 is transparently replaceable by p2.


In your case you are asking if the name of the original object t will refer to the new object, which it will if the requirements above are met.
8.1 and 8.2 are met because you are creating a new object at the exact same location with the exact same type.
8.3 depends on T and this. If neither are const then this requirement is also met.
8.4 is met because t and the newly created object are not potentially overlapping objects. 6.7.2.7 defines potentially overlapping object as a base class subobject or a non-static data member declared with the no_unique_address attribute.
8.5 is met since both objects are subobjects of the Container which is presumed to also be transparently replaceable. If the case where Container is not transparently replaceable, such as if it's is const or a base class subobject, then t is also not transparently replaceable, and the replace function couldn't be called. Making the Container class final may help avoid this trap.

t and the new object are both subobjects. But neither happens to be a potentially-overlapping subobject.

Also, you ignored (8.5), which taken literal seems to put some constraints on the use of Container, although I don't quite understand its intent.

@user17732522 There is no 8.5 in the C++20 standard I am looking at, which admittedly is a draft. I see 8.5 in the latest C++ working draft, but the question is tagged C++20.

@user17732522 8.4 confuses me, I don't understand how an object whose lifetime has ended and a new object in its reused storage can overlap. Maybe I misunderstood the meaning of that requirement.

I think you don't have the final draft before C++20 then. I think it was added during the NB comment phase shortly before finalization.

"potentially-overlapping" is not a relation between the two objects, but a property of an individual object. For example any object that is a base class subobject is potentially-overlapping (without any relation to another object). There should be a definition for the term somewhere in [basic].

@user17732522 If I understand correctly, 8.4 forbids replacing the base class part of an object without replacing the whole object. Is this correct?

@user17732522 If you have a more up to date version, could you please update the answer with the missing requirement.

Yes, because replacing the base class subobject could otherwise overwrite padding that is being reused for the derived classes members (which is where the terminology "potentially-overlapping" originates from).

It is in N4861: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic#life-8.5

@user17732522 Thanks for the helpful feedback. Hopefully the answer is now accurate and sufficiently complete.

Making the class final doesn't seem to be enough, because Container could be a member subobject of a base class subobject. This is why I don't quite understand myself how the last item should be applied here.

I guess there is a defect somewhere and the suggested resolution of CWG 2677 seems like it would make more sense to me.

CWG 2676 is also relevant.
